# jQuery simplify function several checkboxes

Tags: jquery

I have several checkboxes and I would like simplify the next function.

I would like not to repeat each time the same code. I would like use data attribute.

```
<input id="homeView" class="home-checkbox" type="checkbox" />
<input id="homeAll" class="home-checkbox" type="checkbox" />



 $('#homeAll').on('click',function()
        {
            if(this.checked)
            {
                $('.home-checkbox').each
                (
                    function()
                    {
                        this.checked = true;
                    }
                );
            }
            else
            {
                $('.home-checkbox').each
                (
                    function()
                    {
                        this.checked = false;
                    }
                );
            }
        });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ywg9nhp4/2/

Thanks

Comment: Could you be more specific for what you are trying to do ? Whats up with the 'next function' ?

Comment: You should select a version of jQuery under "Frameworks & Extensions" in your fiddle. None of the functions work if you don't.

Comment: is this useful? https://jsfiddle.net/ywg9nhp4/3/

Comment: @GrafiCodeStudio It is missing the feature that if both are :checked, and you uncheck the first it auto unchecks the second.

Comment: @wrxsti I think OP should edit his question, including missing code portions

Comment: @GrafiCodeStudio I don't disagree, I was simply stating a feature I noticed in his fiddle that wasn't in yours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. I used an approach of adding an attribute called 'data-attr'. With this, all you have to do is to add data-attr = 'classname' and it would work for all set of checkboxes.

```
<input id="homeView" class="home-checkbox" data-attr="home-checkbox" type="checkbox" />homeView

<input id="homeAll" class="home-checkbox all"  type="checkbox" />homeAll


<input id="pagesView" class="pages-checkbox" data-attr="pages-checkbox" type="checkbox" />pagesView

<input id="pagesAll" class="pages-checkbox all" type="checkbox" />pagesAll

$('.all').on('click',function()
    {
        var $this = $(this);
        var isChecked = this.checked;
        $('input').each(function()
          {
              if($this.hasClass($(this).attr("data-attr")))
              if(isChecked)
                $(this).prop("checked",true);
            else 
                $(this).prop("checked",false);
          });

    });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ywg9nhp4/5/

UPDATED : Allows uncheck of all if element is unchecked.

```
$('input:checkbox').on('click',function()
    {
        var $this = $(this);
        var isChecked = this.checked;
        var $thisClass = $(this).attr("class");
          $('input').each(function()
          {
              if($this.hasClass($(this).attr("data-attr")))
              {
                  if(isChecked)
                    $(this).prop("checked",true);
                else             
                    $(this).prop("checked",false);    
           }  
           else if($(this).hasClass($thisClass) && !isChecked)
            {                
                 if(isChecked)
                    $(this).prop("checked",true);
                  else             
                    $(this).prop("checked",false); 
                  }

          });

    });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ywg9nhp4/8/

Comment: I would like when I uncheck a checkbox, checkbox "all" is uncheck.

Answer (score 0):

simplified version:

```
$('#homeAll').on('click',function() {
    if(this.checked)
        $('.home-checkbox').prop("checked", true);
    else
        $('.home-checkbox').prop("checked", false);
});
```

DEMO: https://jsfiddle.net/ywg9nhp4/3/

Comment: Your code would only target the checkbox with id="#homeAll", that means for another set of checkboxes, you would need to add the same logic for another id.

Comment: @DinoMyte yep, question was edited after this answer

Answer (score 0):

This a simple! Look:

```js
$('#homeAll').on('click', function() {
  $('.home-checkbox').prop("checked", this.checked);
});

$('#pagesAll').on('click', function() {
  $('.pages-checkbox').prop("checked", this.checked);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="homeView" class="home-checkbox" type="checkbox" /> One Home

<input id="homeAll" class="home-checkbox" type="checkbox" /> All Home

<input id="pagesView" class="pages-checkbox" type="checkbox" /> One pages

<input id="pagesAll" class="pages-checkbox" type="checkbox" />All pages
```

Comment: you'd have to repeat this code for every `#varAll` checkbox

Answer (score 0):

in this demo, for the checkboxes that control other checkboxes' states, just put the class `all`.  this code does not have to be repeated - it targets every element with class `all`.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.all').on('change', function() {
        var allCheck = $(this);
     var classes = $(this).attr('class');       
        $('.' + classes.split(' ')[0] + '').each( function() {
            if (allCheck.is(':checked')) {
                $(this).prop('checked', true);
            }
            else {
                $(this).prop('checked', false);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="homeView" class="home-checkbox" type="checkbox" />                                        
<input id="homeAll" class="home-checkbox all" type="checkbox" />
<br/>
<input id="pagesView" class="pages-checkbox" type="checkbox" />
<input id="pagesAll" class="pages-checkbox all" type="checkbox" />
```